# View model cannot change model property while adding an item to view model list property

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

Old question:

I work with ReactiveUI. If I add a new `ViewModelB` object to a list of this type in `ViewModelA` by `Add` command executing I have to update the `P` property in `ModelA`. But this throws an error. If I remove the throwing of the `PropertyChanged` event in this property, no error occurs. But I need it for reacting to that change in other view models using this data. Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? The code structure is like the following:

Now I got the following information:

If I remove `ViewModelA.UpdateModelValue` or `ViewModelBase.UpdateViewModelValues` from `Model.PropertyChanged` it works fine. As soon as both are added to the event I get an the error in the ReactiveUI library. Only these both properties are added to `Model.PropertyChanged`.

So the code structure changed to the following:

```
class ModelA : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime P; // In the original a property throwing PropertyChanged

    ObservableCollection<ViewModelB> BModels; /* PropertyChanged event passed to ModelA */
}

class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
{        
    IReactiveListDerived<ModelB> BViewModels;

    ReactiveCommand Add;

    ViewModelA(ModelA m)
    {
        Model=m; 
        Model.PropertyChanged+=UpdateModelA;
        BViewModels=m.BModels.CreateDerivedList(x => ViewModelB(x));
        Add=new ReactiveCommand();
        Add.Subscribe(x => Model.BModels.Add(new ModelB()));
    }

    void UpdateModelA(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Name=="BModels")
        {
            Model.P=/*new value*/;
        }
    }
}

class ModelB : INotifyChanged
{
    /* Code */
}

class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase
{
    ViewModelB(ModelB m)
    {
        /* Code */
    }
}

class ViewModelBase : ReactiveObject
{
    INotifyPropertyChanged Model;

    ViewModelBase()
    {
        Model.PropertyChanged+=UpdateViewModelValues();
    }

    void UpdateViewModelValues(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* Code
           Only value types are affected
           Property ViewModelA.BModels is not affected */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a use of the `First` LINQ expression in my code. The corresponding condition can be fulfilled by no items in some cases. So I raised an InvalidOperationException apperently. By using the `FirstOrDefault` LINQ expression the problem is solved.